# Keyboard shortcut for buttons in dialogue box

Tags: macos, keyboard

Given the following options at the bottom of a dialogue box:

[image: Dialogue box with two options with default option selected]

If I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (return) key, it will select **Cancel**, the default selected button. What's the keyboard shortcut to select **Delete** option instead?

Comment: Try Cmd/backspace [or Delete on a short keyboard] same as to discard a file in Finder.

Comment: This also worked.  Can you post as an answer @Tetsujin and I'll upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no set keyboard shortcut for the **Delete** button in this case. If you have enabled full-keyboard access in System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts, you can use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to move focus to the Delete button, and press <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to invoke the Delete command.

[image]

Using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, you can move the focus to the **Delete** button.

Comment: Needed to enable the "All controls" then use `Tab`, then `Space` in this case.  Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 10):

Almost, though not quite, universal on macOS is the use of  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Backspace ⌫</kbd>  [or Delete on keyboards without a distinct Backspace key] to discard, or discard changes.

This should also work to invoke "Don't Save" in dialogs too.
Some apps still accept the alternative of  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>D</kbd>  to do this, but Backspace has been the recommended method for several years [since Lion or so].

Comment: Thanks! It's kind of sad in the era of ubiquitous tool-tips that I had to do a web search to learn this fact. _Gives Apple disapproving look_

Answer (score 1):

For Dialog Boxes in macOS, it usually works by using the <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>*first_letter*</kbd>, where *first_letter* is the first letter of the button you want to select.

Comment: That definitely still work in Adobe apps, & used to be fairly universal, but I can't find another app that still uses it.